# Why does RVM fail to install Ruby 2.0.0 on ROSA?

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm

When trying to install Ruby using RVM on ROSA distro I get the following error:

```
$ rvm install 2.0.0
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: redhat/1
2012
86
64/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p247.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for redhat.
Installing requirements for redhat.
Updating system
asus password required for '/usr/bin/env PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin/:/usr/games:/usr/lib/qt4/bin:/home/asus/bin:/home/asus/.rvm/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin yum install -y gcc-c++ readline-devel libffi-devel openssl-devel autoconf automake libtool bison': Installing required packages: gcc-c++, readline-devel, libffi-devel, openssl-devel, autoconf, automake, libtool, bison
.
Error running 'requirements_centos_libs_install gcc-c++ readline-devel libffi-devel openssl-devel autoconf automake libtool bison',
please read /home/asus/.rvm/log/1379530315_ruby-2.0.0-p247/package_install_gcc-c++_readline-devel_libffi-devel_openssl-devel_autoconf_automake_libtool_bison.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

Obviously RVM does not recognize the system correctly. What can I do to avoid that issue?

Comment: You don't say what version of RVM you're running. First try [`rvm get stable`](http://rvm.io/rvm/upgrading) then retry, otherwise you can contact the RVM authors and provide them with the output of [`rvm info`](http://rvm.io/rvm/info).

Comment: @theTinMan I tried both, the stable and the development release, both throw me the same error. I asked that now in the #rvm IRC but I no one seems to be available for a while now.
What is `rvm show` supposed to put out? The only real information there is, is that RVM recognizes my distro as RedHat, which is wrong (see error). I will probably need something like a manual install for that and I don't know where or how to get that.

Comment: You NEED the RVM guys to tweak the app so it correctly recognizes your OS. If you do it you could get to do it all over again when they finally update. Why not look into rbenv and see if it does what you want. It's less complicated, which is why I like it.

Comment: This is a bug and should be reported here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues